# I want to fill in the json data in order to line in this form

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[please check this image this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2imp.png)

How to fill input boxes when adding more rows to fill (look at image)?

**This is how I load the json data**

```
#loading Json file
with  open('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test fl/json/1.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#Property
property = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".AssetFormTraitSectionreact__DivContainer-sc-j28e67-0:nth-child(1) .AssetFormTraitSection--side .Iconreact__Icon-sc-1gugx8q-0")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", property)
```

**These lines to click the 'add more' box**

```
#Add more 
add = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gIDfxn")
add.click()
```

**These lines to fill the input box**

```
#Attributes
for attr in data["attributes"]:
    add = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".AssetPropertiesFormreact__TrContainer-sc-g5scfi-0:nth-child(1) .AssetPropertiesForm--name-input > .browser-default")
    add.send_keys(attr["trait_type"])
    print("Attribute key"+attr["trait_type"] +" is added")

for attr in data["attributes"]:
    add = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".AssetPropertiesFormreact__TrContainer-sc-g5scfi-0:nth-child(1) .AssetPropertiesForm--value-input > .browser-default")
    add.send_keys(attr["value"])
    print("Attribute key"+attr["value"] +" is added")
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Please don't link external images to explain your problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

Taking what you had and combining them you would be able to do the following.

As for getting the last boxes that you added you need to use `.find_elements()` instead of `.find_element()` and then index into the last element with [-1] to get your code looking like:

```
import time

#loading Json file
with  open('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test fl/json/1.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#Property
property = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".AssetFormTraitSectionreact__DivContainer-sc-j28e67-0:nth-child(1) .AssetFormTraitSection--side .Iconreact__Icon-sc-1gugx8q-0")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", property)

# cycle through the attributes
for attr in data["attributes"]:
    add_type = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, ".AssetPropertiesForm--name-input")[-1]
    #add_type = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".AssetPropertiesFormreact__TrContainer-sc-g5scfi-0:nth-child(1) .AssetPropertiesForm--name-input > .browser-default")[-1]

    add_type.send_keys(attr["trait_type"])
    print("Attribute key"+attr["trait_type"] +" is added")

    add_name = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, ".AssetPropertiesForm--value-input")[-1]
    #add_name = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".AssetPropertiesFormreact__TrContainer-sc-g5scfi-0:nth-child(1) .AssetPropertiesForm--value-input > .browser-default")[-1]
    add_name.send_keys(attr["value"])
    print("Attribute key"+attr["value"] +" is added")

    if attr != data['attributes'][-1]:    #Add more 
        add_more = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gIDfxn")
        add_more.click()

    time.sleep(5) # to make sure that the box is loaded -- unsure if actually needed
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QvdYQHo

Comment: check the image first box fill all the data's

Comment: @ShashithHarshana try the new edited version -- the error is that your CSS selector was narrowed in on that specific element and not the general input types (still unsue if the selector is the best as I can't see a live version of the site, but trying what I know)